# Which form is better in this case

Tags: definite-article

Shall I say "All the records that I buy in the USA" or"All records that I buy in the USA"

I think the first one is better because it is not all records in general  but only these that I buy in the USA

Answer (score 0):

Both are possible. When would you use one or the other? Let's try to complete the sentences:

"All the records that I buy in the USA turn out to be awesome!"

"All records that I buy in the USA are subject to import tax."

Without "the", the phrase is more terse, to-the-point, and serious.

With "the", it's more conversational.

Since the collection of records which you actually buy are actually a definite group, "the" is appropriate.  The second sentence could be worded "All records that I might choose to buy in the USA are subject to import tax.". *If* you buy the record, it will be subject to tax. Otherwise not. So it's less definite.  And less in need of a definite article.

With "the" seems to be the most expected and normal, however both variants are allowed.

The second sentence could have included "the". Either way.

And the first sentence... could it have omitted "the"?  Probably it should be kept there.